# How to use dictionary values to calculate sum of weighted values without explicitly defined weights?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, weighted-average

As an example I have a dictionary as follows:

```
mydict = {A:['asdasd',2,3], B:['asdasd',4,5], C:['rgerg',9,10]}
```

How can I get just one number that is essentially the sum of the weighted values of all the keys in the dict (this example: `A, B, C`) weighted by the last number in the list (`list[-1]`)?

So for instance, this would be the sum of:

```
(2/15)*3 + (4/15)*5 + (9/15)*10 = 7.73
```

Where 15 is the sum of 2,4,9.

At the moment I'm creating too many variables that just iterate through the dictionary. I'm sure there's a quick efficient Python way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact that `(2/15)*3 + (4/15)*5 + (9/15)*10` is just the same as `(2*3 + 4*5 + 9*10)/15`, you don't have to pre-calculate the total, so you could do this in one pass of the dict with `reduce`, but perhaps it isn't as readable.

Turning the dict into a series of tuples:

```
>>> d = {A:['asdasd',2,3], B:['asdasd',4,5], C:['rgerg',9,10]}
>>> from functools import reduce    # Py3
>>> x,y = reduce(lambda t, e: (t[0]+e[0], t[1]+e[1]), ((a*b, a) for _,a,b in d.values()))
>>> x/y   # float(y) in Py2
7.733333333333333
```

Or without the intermediate generator and using an initial value (probably the fastest):

```
>>> x,y = reduce(lambda t, e: (t[0]+e[1]*e[2], t[1]+e[1]), d.values(), (0,0))
>>> x/y   # float(y) in Py2
7.733333333333333
```

Or you could zip up the results and sum:

```
>>> x,y = (sum(x) for x in zip(*((a*b, a) for _,a,b in d.values())))
>>> x/y   # float(y) in Py2
7.733333333333333
```

Or you could do what @ranlot suggests though I would avoid the intermediate lists:

```
>>> sum(a*b for _,a,b in d.values())/sum(a for _,a,b in d.values())
7.733333333333333
```

Though this seems to be fractionally slower than either of the ones above.

Comment: Thank you. I really like the first option you gave me. It was the quickest method with the data I'm using. This is what I was after, renlot gave a similar approach I had gone with just a lot more succinctly done. I'll reiterate my query I made to renlot. I'm creating the dictionary on the fly for other purposes and I've just added these variables. For speed sake do you think I should be doing saving them for something other than in the dict?

Comment: Without more details it's hard to tell, you could perhaps avoid the adding the values to the dict and then calculating by just calculating the results on the fly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I've been playing with it and not figuring it our. Syntax wise how would I, using your reduce lamdba method, include an if statement if say e[0]=='asdasd'?

Comment: I've tried something like: x,y = reduce(lambda t, e: True if e[0]=='asdasd' (t[0]+e[1]*e[2], t[1]+e[1]) else False, dict.values(), (0,0))

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, it might be worth asking a separate question describing the problem and your expected output. Are you just trying to `filter` on 'asdasd'?

Comment: Yea I was just wanting to filter, but if you think I should ask another question I will. If I use ranlot's example it would be the equivalent of: normConst = sum(dict[x][-2] for x in dict if dict[x][0]=='asdasd')                        
print sum(dict[x][-1]*dict[x][-2] / float(normConst) for x in dict if dict[x][0]=='asdasd')

Comment: `x, y = reduce(lambda v, e: (v[0]+e[1]*e[2], v[1]+e[1]), filter(lambda e: e[0] == 'asdasd', d.values()), (0,0))`

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict = {'A':['asdasd', 2, 3], 'B':['asdasd', 4, 5], 'C':['rgerg', 9, 10]}
normConst = sum([dict[x][-2] for x in myDict])
sum([dict[x][-1]*dict[x][-2] / float(normConst) for x in myDict])
```

Comment: you could use `sum(..)` instead of `sum([..])`. You could use `for v in some_dict.values()`, to get values. Don't use `dict` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin.

Comment: A question about this: In terms of speed, I'm still essentially having to iterate of the dictionary, like when I use iteritems for example. Since I'm creating the dictionary, should I be storing the 2 and 3's in a vector as I read down the file that is creating the dictionary/list, or is there another way like a running tally that would be faster?